# Need assistance with restarting Excel when opening document

Tags: vba, excel

I have written this code which automaticly runs a macro when opening Excel. This macro will create a messagebox that appears. After you press "OK" on this messagebox Excel is going to restart. It is in this part I am having difficulties since I only manage to close the Workbook and not re-open it.

```
Sub auto_open()
Dim x As String


With CheckTekla
If .GetConnectionStatus = False Then
Call Shell("C:\Program Files\Tekla Structures\19.1\nt\bin\TeklaStructures.exe")
MsgBox "TEXT"
x = ActiveWorkbook.Name
Workbooks(x).Close False
Workbooks.Open x

Else
'do nothing
End If
End With

End Sub
```

The part which is supposed to restart Excel is:

```
Dim x As String
x = ActiveWorkbook.Name
Workbooks(x).Close False
Workbooks.Open x
```

Any help is appreciated.

Regards,

Comment: Are you trying to restart Excel, or open and close the Workbook?

Comment: I am trying to restart Excel.

Comment: The code you posted needs to be outside of the workbook you are trying to close and open (say, in another workbook open in the same Excel session). Restarting Excel, from within Excel, is a little more complicated.

Comment: Hi Rusan,

I see, if I instead want to restart the workbook, should  just change the code to: `set x=ActiveWorkbook.name`  ?

Comment: Is it a correct solution?

Answer (score 0):

Restarting Excel from VBA is impossible.

You could run this:

```
Application.Quit
```

However, this will just close Excel, and will not restart it, since the macro will stop running after Excel closes.  So, you would have to start Excel manually after it closes.

Answer (score 0):

As above said, restarting excel is impossible from vba in excel (you could call an external vbs script that closes and opens excel though)
However, you clarified that you want to close and reopen the workbook, try to set a variable and close it. Capture the name as FullName (with path) and open it again, without path, it won't work.

```
Sub auto_open()
Dim x As String
Dim wb as workbook

With CheckTekla
If .GetConnectionStatus = False Then
Call Shell("C:\Program Files\Tekla Structures\19.1\nt\bin\TeklaStructures.exe")
MsgBox "TEXT"

Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
x = wb.FullName
wb.Close False
Set wb = Workbooks.Open(x)
Else
'do nothing
End If
End With

End Sub
```